# .htaccess RewriteBase

Tags: .htaccess

In my .htaccess folder I'm using RewriteRule to forward `music.php?artist=name` to `music/name`. My problem is, if you click another link, instead of going to `site.com/music/otherartist`, it goes to `site.com/music/name/otherartist` (you're still stuck in the "music/name" directory). I've tried adding

```
RewriteBase /
```

and I get the error "Object not found." I'm sure the solution to this is really simple, but I haven't figured it out yet. :/

Comment: Hi, please give the rewrite rule you are using. It seems that it is affecting urls that it shouldn't.

Comment: This is all I have so far:
`RewriteRule ^music/([^/]+) music.php?artist=$1
RewriteRule ^music music.php`

Comment: in most cases you'll have to stop using relative urls in your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your links to be absolute URLs or add a relative URI base to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```